# Zariski open sets are dense in analytic topology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

How does one show that if $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ is nonempty and Zariski open then $U$ is also dense in the analytic topology on $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is enough to show that the complement of $U$ has empty interior. Also, that complement is contained in the zero set $Z$ of a non-constant polynomial $f$, so it is enough to show that $Z$ does not contain open sets.

If $z\in Z$ is a point in the interior of $Z$, then the Taylor series of $f$ at $z$ is of course zero. Since $f$ is an entire function, this is absurd.

Comment: +1: this is a slicker argument than mine. 

Answer (score 10):

It is equivalent to show that the complement, say $V$, has empty interior.  In fact $V$ has measure zero (say, with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{C}^n$; any measure which is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure would serve as well).  If $V$ is smooth, this is very standard: the Implicit Function Theorem (or something like that).  In general, you can use the fact that $V$ has a relatively open subset which is a smooth manifold whose complement has positive codimension and finish off by induction.

Comment: Sard's theorem would show the measure zero part.

Comment: Sard's theorem claims that the *image* of something has measure zero, not that the *preimage* of something does, Anweshi

Comment: Actually, my first draft of the answer included a reference to Sard's theorem.  Upon reflection, I took it out.  I do maintain that, whatever particular theorem you want to cite, a closed submanifold of Euclidean space has measure zero, and that this is not hard to show!

Answer (score 8):

Here is a theorem from the "Complex Varieties" section of Mumford's "Red Book of Varieties and Schemes" (2nd edition):

Theorem:  Let $X$ be a complex variety and $U \subseteq X$ a nonempty (Zariski) open subvariety.  Then $U$ is dense in $X$ for the analytic topology.

(I think varieties for Mumford are always irreducible.)

Comment: If they weren't irreducible, then his theorem would be false for him :)