# Zero measurability of zero-sets of polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, measure-theory, polynomials

Could anyone point me to a reference showing that the zero set of a polynomial in $n \ge 2$ variables has Lebesgue measure zero? I wonder if there are pathological examples, and  some conditions needed for this.

Here is a sketch of an argument I have: Let $p(x,y) \equiv p(x,y_1,\dots,y_n)$ be a polynomial of degree $d$ (with real coefficients say) in $n+1$ variables. Assume that the polynomial is not identically zero. Let $A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^{n+1} :\; p(x,y) = 0\}$. I would like to argue that this set has Lebesgue measure zero, by induction on $n$.

Consider the set of all $y$ for which $x \mapsto p(x,y)$ is identically zero, i.e. $B = \{y \in \mathbb R ^n:\; p(\cdot,y) = 0\}$. Since the coefficients of $x$ in  $x \mapsto p(x,y)$ are polynomials in $y$, $B$ can be written as the zero set of a system of polynomials in $y$. By induction assumption, $B$ should have measure zero. Now $A \subset ([0,1]\times B) \cup (A \cap ([0,1]\times B^c))$
where 
\begin{align}
A_2 := A \cap ([0,1]\times B^c) &= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^{n+1} : y\in B^c,\; \; p(x,y) = 0\}\\
&= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^{n+1} : y\in B^c,\; \; x\in Z_y\}
\end{align}
where $Z_y$ is the zero set of $p(\cdot,y)$ which is a finite set with at most $d$ elements. Since $A$ and $B$ are measurable, $A_2$ is measurable (and $Z_y$ is certainly measurable), and we can use disintegration theorem (?) to get
$$
\mu_{n+1}(A_2) = \int_{y \in B^c} \mu_n(Z_y) dy = 0
$$ 
where $\mu_n$ is the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure. Similarly by Fubini $\mu_{n+1}([0,1]\times B) = 0$. It follows that $\mu_{n+1}(A) =0$.

Is there something wrong with the above argument?

EDIT: I guess one has to rule out cases like this $p(x,y) = x^2 + ((y+1)^2 - y^2-2y-1)x$ where a coefficient is identically zero for my argument to go through. Can we say that for every polynomial there is another one where these trivial identities have been removed, and they are the same as functions (or at least have the same zero sets)? Unfortunately, I don't know/remember enough algebraic geometry to know if what I am saying is something obviously true or obviously false or even phrased correctly?

Comment: Gunning and Rossi prove, on p.9, the zero locus of a holomorphic function has Lebesgue measure zero, if you want the complex case.

Comment: @roy smith, Great! Thanks. Would that imply the real case? It doesn't seem to be a direct implication, the dimension of the Lebesgue measures are different for the real and complex cases.

Comment: Follows from existence of a triangulation with smooth open simplices.

Comment: @Misha, Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Your argument works fine.  If $p(x,y) = p_k(y) x^k + \dots + p_1(y) x + p_0(y)$, then $B$ is the intersection of the zero sets of the $p_i$.  Some of the $p_i$ could be the zero polynomial, but by assumption, at least one is not.   So its zero set has measure zero; thus so does $B$.  Also, your "disintegration theorem" is just Fubini again; to make it easier to see, try writing your measure expressions as the integral of an indicator function.

Comment: By a linear change of variables you can ensure your polynomial is monic in the x variable. This will simplify your argument.

Comment: @NateEldredge, thanks, yes you are right. I forgot that Fubini in fact says something about general measurable sets and not just products.

Comment: @MohanRamachandran, thanks, but which aspect it simplifies? Not sure if I can see what you mean.

Comment: @passerby51 The set B will be empty when p is monic in x .

Comment: @MohanRamachandran, Oh... I see. Thanks.

Comment: Another proof by mathematical induction can be found in this article:
Okamoto, M. (1973). Distinctness of the Eigenvalues of a Quadratic form in a Multivariate Sample. The Annals of Statistics, 1(4), 763–765. https://doi.org/10.1214/aos/1176342472

Answer (score 4):

See

S. Lojasiewicz, Triangulation of semi-analytic sets, Ann. Scu. Norm. di Pisa, 18 (1964), 449-474.

where it is proven that real algebraic (actually, even semi-analytic) sets admit stratifications whose strata are smooth manifolds.  Of course, you need to assume that your polynomial is nonconstant, to ensure that there are no strata open in $R^n$.

Edit. I just realized that Sergei Ivanov gave a very elementary proof in his answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25513/zariski-closed-sets-in-cn-are-of-measure-0).

Comment: A nice aspect of this argument is that it extends to all o-minimal structures.